# Jetpack ComposeView Keyboard is overlapping OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

In Kotlin Jetpack ComposeView: Keyboard is overlapping OutlinedTextField in devices with smaller screens .
Device details:
Name : Nokia 6.1
Android version: 10
Model : TA-1089
[password field overlapping gif link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4hOr.gif)
below is the code kotlin and manifest code used

```
                            value = passwordText.value!!,
                            onValueChange = {
                                passwordText.value = it
                                enableLogin =
                                    studentIDText.value.isNullOrEmpty()
                                        .not() && passwordText.value.isNullOrEmpty()
                                        .not()
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                                .border(
                                    border = BorderStroke(
                                        1.dp,
                                        colorResource(id = R.color.light_white)
                                    ),
                                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
                                ),
                            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
                            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
                                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                            ),
                            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                                onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }),
                            placeholder = {
                                SBText(
                                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.enter_password),
                                    size = 16.sp,
                                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.light_white),
                                    font = SBFont.WorksansRegular,
                                    lineHeight = 16.sp,
                                )
                            },
                            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                                textColor = colorResource(id = R.color.grey),
                                cursorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.grey),
                                focusedBorderColor = colorResource(id = R.color.light_white),
                                unfocusedBorderColor = colorResource(id = R.color.light_white)
                            ),
                            maxLines = 1,
                            singleLine = true
                        )
```

```
            android:name=".ui.SBActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SB.NoActionBar"
            android:showWhenLocked="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
            android:taskAffinity="">
```

Comment: Can try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to Manifest if that suits your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your manifest file
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Inside your MainActivity/EntryActivity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            App()
        }

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(android.R.id.content)) { view, insets ->
            val bottom = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom
            view.updatePadding(bottom = bottom)
            insets
        }
    }
}
```